# A basic question about the meaning of dB of an antenna radiation pattern

Tags: antenna

I know that dB is always a **power ratio**. And to obtain dB there must be a reference power or voltage measured with respect to another.

Below is an antenna pattern which shows a -3dB point for instance:

[image]

What does that mean literally? Can it be explained clearly? -3dB obtained by dividing which units? And what is relative to what? Basically I'm asking the idea of antenna pattern and the dB associations. And how is that obtained.

**Edit:**

[image]

**Edit 2:**

I marked two points A and B in X, Y, Z coordinates. A is on the plot surface B is not. Red and pink share the same XY point and different Z. Are the powers at A and B same? If not is the power pattern only valid for that plotted surface? How about the rest of the sapce?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See the point at the end of the lobe - it's called the "peak output power point". The point called "-3 dB from peak" tells me that at this point, if there was an RF power density of (say) 100 watts per sq metre at the peak point then there will only be 50 watts per sq metre at the -3 dB point.

-3 dB when converted to a power ratio is \$10^{-3/10}\$ = 0.50119 (or basically a half if pin-point accuracy isn't required).

Comment: So basically are you telling that first the max power point detected as 0dB and the rest of the points are referenced to that point?

Comment: If the max power point is referenced as 0 dB (an arbitrary unit) then the noted points on the side lobes are - 3 dB. The term dBi refers to the power density output of a real antenna with respect to the theoretical so-called isotropic antenna. It is a theoretical example of an antenna that emits equally in all directions (a useful point of comparison but impractical).

Comment: I don't get it please see my new edit. It doesn't look like the same way of procedure is applied to obtain the dB rad pattern. You see the 0dB is not the max point. The dBs are positive. Why is that?

Comment: It is from a patch antenna data-sheet http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/1153042/swlp.2450.12.4.b.02_taoglas.html?page=5#datasheet

Comment: 0 dB is an arbitrary value for a start. To make it meaningful you need to append it with (say) m to make dBm and this then means that 0 dBm refers to 1 milli watt of power. dBuV would be a signal level (in dB) relative to a voltage level of 1 uV as another example. So, the picture you have added is meaningless and the point marked -3.30159 is also meaningless.

Comment: I've checked the link and the picture appears to meaningless without some context.

Comment: Do you mean there is no clear context? Did you see the datasheet's first pages?

Comment: Yes, I read the whole data sheet and it is quite unfathomable what the polar plots represent as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: In Edit 2 I explained the confusion of reading power pattern. I would like to hear your input. Thanks.

Comment: @user134429 the plot surface is just an arbitrary surface and of course RF power extends until undetectable. Point B is beyond the plot surface so it will have less power associated with it. Your question is evolving from what was asked originally and you should bear in mind that this site isn't for open-ended questions. If you want to raise a new question about interpreting polar plots then this would be acceptable of course.

Comment: For the rest of space I would urge you to study the theoretical isotropic antenna and the Friis formula that describes power levels versus distance versus frequency from an antenna.

Comment: I think I got what you mean. The power changes for A and B but the pattern remains the same. We can think of concentric patterns shapes in the entire space I guess.

Comment: But after some point would that pattern become flat and becomes  plane waves? Strange that data sheets do not mention the distance for the pattern shape limits.

Comment: The patterns from concentric shapes, correct. At infinity, a section of a circle becomes a flat line!

Answer (score 1):

The antenna pattern you see is an example of a so-called *polar plot*, i.e. a plot of a function in a [polar coordinate system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system). In this kind of plots you draw a function r = f(θ), where r is the distance from the origin and θ is the angle measured with respect to a reference axis (in your case it is the horizontal axis pointing right).

Note: θ in your diagram is not the θ I'm referring to.

Your f is, in this case, the radiated power from the antenna.

Therefore the antenna pattern contour show the power transmitted in each direction (direction identified by θ) as points of the curve that are farther from the origin as the power in that direction increases.

This kind of plot is useful for quantities that depends on some angle representing a direction in space, for example, since the "lobes" of the contour show clearly in which directions you have a peak of the emission.

The main lobe, if it exists in the pattern, is the lobe whose "peak" lies farthest from the origin and hence identifies the direction of maximum emission.

As your diagram states, the -3dB points are relative to the peak of the main lobe. This means that the power emitted by the antenna in the directions identified by those two points is half the power emitted in the direction where the main lobe peak lies.

To be more precise, a radiation pattern like that is just a 2D section of a 3D surface, known as the *radiation solid* of the antenna (or [3D radiation pattern)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radiation_pattern). If the radiation solid is has a cylindrical symmetry around the 2D polar axis, then a single section may be sufficient to give the idea of the whole radiation characteristics of the antenna. Otherwise you could need of other sections, across different planes (see also [this link](http://www.antenna-theory.com/basics/radpattern.php)):

[image]

Comment: Sometimes I also see dBi. Is that the same thing with dB?

Comment: @user134429 dBi is a relative measure (in dB) relative to an isotropic radiator.

Comment: Please see my new edit. It doesn't look like the same way of procedure is applied to obtain the dB rad pattern. You see the 0dB is not the max point. The dBs are positive. Why is that?

Comment: @user134429 your edit is not clear. Where did you get that second plot? There is not enough information on it to understand its meaning unequivocally.

Comment: It is from a patch antenna data-sheet http://www.datasheetlib.com/datasheet/1153042/swlp.2450.12.4.b.02_taoglas.html?page=5#datasheet

Comment: If I take a single section as XY plane all planes would have different pattern. Can you see in my edit if the height of the section is indicated? It just says XY plane. XY plane at what Z?

Comment: @user134429 The xy plane is what it says - it is the plane in all directions (x and y directions) with z at 0.

Comment: Please see Edit 2 about confusion on pattern's meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Isotropic antenna or radiator is a hypothetical (not physically realizable) concept, used as a useful reference to describe real antennas for their **peak gain** in one direction.

• For example the spherical Sun is an Isotropic radiator
 • If you can imagine integrating all the energy in a sphere, then every ideal antenna "could always" have the same spherical output power  or 0dBi average...
      •    BUT antennae are defined as having a peak gain in one direction only of  something greater than 0dBi with a some relative polar pattern.
 • the ideal dipole has a peak gain of 1.15 dBi since the field loses strength along on the axis yet the total integrated surface area * gain = 0dBi average
 • If an antenna cannot be perfectly matched at some frequency then subtracted from the diversity gain are the mismatch losses and the result is the net peak gain.

The same concept is used for light magnification with a parabolic reflector or lens where the beamwidth and gain are ideal tradeoffs while losses naturally occurring are added.